# Which class to Mock for to bypass Springboot security in integration tests

Tags: spring-security, integration-testing, spock, spring-boot-test

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ContextLoadingSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate

    def '/ should load the context'() {
        when:
        ResponseEntity<Object> entity = testRestTemplate.getForEntity('/', Object.class)

        then:
        entity.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
            return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .basicAuthorization('user', 'xxxxxxxx')
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a TestConfiguration doesn't seem correct to me here. The credentials should be in 'application.yml' and the authentication call should have been mocked. Please suggest a better way of writing this test.